# How to Make GridView scrolling animation in flutter

Tags: animation, gridview, uimotioneffect

I am using the grid view builder I only wanted to show this animation when scroll. Can anyone guide me about this? Here is the Video.
https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5fef5bc8c4ec0325d5bb456c/5ff630549d5e5313981becd9/5772189ca10a4e769416d0d38632bca1/movie.mov